# How to center rectangles on position in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have a graph where I have both circles and rectangles along the ticks of my x-axis. I'd like to be able to center all elements on the ticks of the x-axis. Circles are automatically placed in the center and scaled with a radius attribute, but with rectangles, I am not able to move it as I am using an ordinal scale to create my x-axis values.

This is how much graph looks like: http://puu.sh/gmCkZ/37ab176161.png

It can be seen that the squares upper-left corner is the position I want to be it's center.

My code for the x-axis looks like the following:

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 1);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
    x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }));
```

How can i center a figure like the square in a certain position? In this case, on a specific area of the x-axis?

***EDIT***

Added SVG code for square:

```
var square = svgbody
        .selectAll("nodes.rect")
        .data(["B", "L"]);

    square.exit()
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", 0)
        .remove();

    square.enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "squareNodes");

    square
        .attr("x", function(d){ return x(d);})
        .attr("y", function(d){return y(statusText);} )
        .attr("width",19)
        .attr("height",19)
        .attr("rx", "3")
        .attr("ry", "3" )
        .style('opacity', NODE_OPACITY)
        .style('fill', "green");
```

Comment: Are you able to add a class to the squares, or no?

Comment: Yes I can add a class to the square. Why?

Comment: I assume you add your <rect> element somewhere in the DOM where you had a translation. You can check and compare if the <circle> elements and the <rect> elements you append differ in 1) either the selection where they are appended to or 2) the setting of your x attribute (and cx attribute of the <circle>...e.g. .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.name); })...

Comment: can you show the code where you append the rect and (add the selection in case it's a variable)?

Comment: @ee2Dev Yes of course I added it now. I'm not sure I understand your other comment however :(

Comment: Can you show the line in your code, where you have the selection...append("rect")...?

Comment: then you should look in the selection "nodes.rect". Alos, you shouldn't in the enter update pattern always repeat the selection in enter ().append() function. In your code you select "nodes.rect" and then enter rect.squareNodes. See http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
squareSize = 19;
square
    .attr("x", function(d){ return x(d) - squareSize/2;})
    .attr("y", function(d){return y(statusText) - squareSize/2;} )
    .attr("width",squareSize)
    .attr("height",squareSize)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If the square is 50px wide, and you have a class called .square:

```
.square{
   position: relative;
   right: 25px;
}
```

Just move it over half.  See if that works.

Here is a fiddle to show you what I mean.

http://jsfiddle.net/plushyObject/hkwwxq9j/

Comment: Thank you for the response. This piece of code doesn't affect the square at all however, it stays in it's position still.

Comment: Ah I see that's why I asked if we could create a class for it.

Comment: Perhaps try doing something similar. Move it left half its width. Unfortunately not very family with SVG.

Comment: I tried doing it with the class I created for it, but I couldn't make it work. I got another answer that helped me by changing it using D3 framework. But thank you very much!